# No such file or directory when opening file in memory with ZipRuby Zip::File

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm consuming an api that replies with a zip file in the contents of the body of the http response. I'm able to unzip the file and write each file to disk using the example at the zip-ruby wiki (https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home):

```
Zip::Archive.open('filename.zip') do |ar|  # except I'm opening from a string in memory
  ar.each do |zf|
    if zf.directory?
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(zf.name)
    else
      dirname = File.dirname(zf.name)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(dirname) unless File.exist?(dirname)

      open(zf.name, 'wb') do |f|
        f << zf.read
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, I don't want to write the files to disk. Instead, I want create an active record object, and set a paperclip file attachment:

```
    asset = Asset.create(:name => zf.name)
    asset.file  = open(zf.name, 'r')
    asset.save
```

What's odd is the open statement in the first example that writes the file to disk works consistently.  However, when I want to just open the zf (Zip::File) as a generic File in memory, I will sometimes get:

```
*** Errno::ENOENT Exception: No such file or directory - assets/somefilename.png
```

How can I assign the Zip::File zipruby creates to the paperclip file without getting this error?

Comment: was this ever resolved?

Comment: I don't think so, cause I faced it now :)